# Apple Maps app or MapKit for turn by turn navigation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I would like to create an app, that would show navigation to some marker. It would be best if that navigation could be provided inside an app, however I am not sure if that's possible (at least with MapKit). If my app would launch Apple Maps app for navigation, could my app update destination location? The thing is in most cases my destination should change with time. What are my options?

I done some googling, found that [Skobbler](http://www.skobbler.com) a SDK for in app navigation, but it increases app size over 100Mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in an app which takes the coordinates from a plist, maps them and then provides directions from the user location to the map destination point selected. Try this link:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_MKDirections_to_get_iOS_8_Map_Directions_and_Routes